# how to wrap present but unknown element

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapper

I have a script that I give to clients. The client can put it anywhere in their html body. It could be placed between a div, td, p, or anything similar.

The script looks something like this:

```
<script id="myExample" src="http://www.mydomain.com/example.js" ></script>
```

Now, in "example.js" I want to wrap my script dynamically.

I've tried something like:

```
// create the container div
$("#myExample").wrap('<div></div>');
document.getElementById("myExample").firstChild.setAttribute("id","myExampleContainer");
```

...but I get an error:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...).firstChild is null
```

Can wrapping the present element (which is a js) with a div, and giving the wrapper an id possible?

UPDATE: See the answer by Musa, below.

Two working solutions:

```
// create the container div
$("#myExample").wrap('<div></div>');
document.getElementById("myExample").parentNode.setAttribute("id","myExampleContainer");
```

...or:

```
$("#myExample").wrap('<div id="myExampleContainer"></div>');
```

Comment: Do you actually expect the script tag to have child elements ?

Comment: Point taken. I'm going to correct my question and answer. I stated something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapper is the parent of `#myExample` not a child, so you'll have to do

```
document.getElementById("myExample").parentNode.setAttribute("id","myExampleContainer");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/awz8U/1/
or just add the id in the div

```
$("#myExample").wrap('<div id="myExampleContainer"></div>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/awz8U/2/

Comment: You are exactly right. Thank you. The other answer was not wrong, given what I stated. But your answer is the working one.

Answer (score 1):

Should be [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.childNodes) instead of `firstChild`:

```
document.getElementById("myExample").childNodes[ 0 ].setAttribute...
```

But don't forget to check if parent has child nodes:

```
if( document.getElementById("myExample") && document.getElementById("myExample").childNodes.length ) {
    // some stuff here...
}
```

Comment: `#myExample` is the script node, it doesn't have any children.

Comment: Yeah, what I tried could never have worked. I'm going to update what I did to correct this, based on the answers and comments given.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("myExample").wrap($("<div/>", { id: "myExampleContainer" }));
```